# Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.UserControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My code is this 
![enter image description here][1]

But I am getting a Null exception error :(

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim textquestionselected As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim imagequestionselected As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim text_question_id As Integer
        Dim image_question_id As Integer
        For Each gridviewrow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If (CType(gridviewrow.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked) Then

                text_question_id = Convert.ToInt16(CType(gridviewrow.FindControl("small_int_question_id"), Label).Text)
                textquestionselected.Add(text_question_id)
            End If
        Next
        For Each gridviewrow1 As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
            If (CType(gridviewrow1.FindControl("CheckBox2"), CheckBox).Checked) Then

                image_question_id = CType(gridviewrow1.FindControl("small_int_question_id"), Label).Text
                imagequestionselected.Add(image_question_id)
            End If
        Next
```

[image]

I used bound Field instead Label .. but same error

Comment: Can you actually post the `code` instead of an image?

Comment: When you have code, please copy/paste it into your answer as actual text, don't embed it as an image. You can search text within an image, images are on different domains and can be blocked, and it's hard to re-use your code in an answer.

Comment: We need to be able to see the error log clearly.

Comment: I have posted the Code instead of Image .. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the type of  row it is; it's probably the header or footer row.  Check the [RowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property to make sure it's a DataRow.

```
if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   //Check control 
}
```

Also according to your subject, make sure the type you are converting is the same.  It would really help to see a snippet of the markup.

Comment: I think the error is in 'Label' keyword in this line ..  Convert.ToInt16(CType(gridviewrow.FindControl("small_int_question_id"), Label).Text)

Comment: Right but without checking the type of row it is, you could be trying to find it in the header row, which doesn't exist.  Also try using `gridviewrow.Cells[index].FindControl` to see if that makes a difference.